# Use scientific notation for Python plots by default

Tags: python, matplotlib

Simple question: how do I get Python to use scientific notation in its plots by default? From various posts on SO I can write something like

```
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(linspace(1e6,2e6),linspace(1e6,1e7))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(linspace(8e6,9e6),linspace(2e6,2.5e7))

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(-2,2))
plt.show()
```

but `ticklabel_format` only acts on the last plot generated by matplotlib. (If `plt.ticklabel_format()` is put at the beginning of the code, I also get a blank figure showing the x,y axes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the default behaviour of matplotlib by edditing your "rc" file. See [Customizing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

In you case, it looks like you could adjust the item:

```
axes.formatter.limits : -2, 2 # use scientific notation if log10
                              # of the axis range is smaller than the
                              # first or larger than the second
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is it possible to just temporarily change the rc file within my Python script? I will eventually run my code (not this MWE) on HPC, so I just need to redefine `axes.formatter.limits` for the duration of the code runtime.

Comment: As outlined (in the linked document)[https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings], you can place the lines `import matplotlib as mpl 
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-2,2)` at the beginning of your script to change the behavior locally